# ASP.NET Button Text Showing Incorrectly with :Disabled psuedoclass

Tags: html, css, asp.net, css-selectors

I have an ASP.Net Webforms page which has several controls on it, including several different sized asp.net buttons.  There are certain times when I need to disable a button or buttons on this page, which I am able to do without issue, but the issue is that when I do disable them, the text on the button appears to have a carriage return in the text, making the text appear lower on the button then when the button is enabled.  (Please see the image below...Edit, apparently I don't have enough points to post an image.)

The image I wanted to post shows the text of the disabled button aligned at the bottom with half the bottom half of the word missing with the text of the enabled button showing correctly.

Here is the CSS code I am using.

```
.big, .medium, .med-big, .small, .smaller{
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-family: 'Oswald',sans-serif;
    /*text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(109, 5, 5, 0.8);*/
    color:black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;


}

.big:active, .medium:active, .small:active, .med-bid:active, .smaller:active{
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset;
    outline: 0 none;

}

.big:disabled, .medium:disabled, .med-big:disabled, .small:disabled, .smaller:disabled{
    display: inline;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-family: 'Oswald',sans-serif;
    color:grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC

}

.big{
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 17px 10px 10px 10px;
    font-size:24px;

}
```

I am disabling the buttons through server side code simply by setting the button's Enabled Property to false.

I'm in the process of moving from more of a Winforms developer (of many years) to a web developer, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  I also did search the site for an answer to this issue, and although there are several posts regarding CSS styling a disabled, button, I could not find one for this specific issue.

Thanks.

Comment: It is surprising that you do not see the shift in enabled state. `padding: 17px 10px 10px 10px;` seems to be the one to blame, check out [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f51auctq/)

Comment: Andrei, Thank you for doing the jsfiddle.  I appreciate that. I applied that to my css file, and even added the "big nopadding" class to the button via server side code, but am still seeing the same issue.  I know the button has the correct class as seen by using the F12 dev tool for IE (using IE 11, non compatibility mode for the testing).  I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Here is what I am seeing via the F12 tool:  <input name="ctl00$MainContent$cmdSave" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled big nopadding" id="MainContent_cmdSave" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" type="submit" value="Save">

Comment: Andrei, nevermind my last answer.  I had a duplicate disabled selector for the .big class further down in the css file that I hadn't commented out.  Your code did the trick and it's working like it should.  If I can mark this as the answer I will be more than happy to.  Thanks again for taking the time out to read and provide help.  Appreciate it!!

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out. However my comment did nothing new - I just copied over your code and made an assumption. This is not an answer, and I am not able to turn it into such. If you want to make some difference here, the best way would be to make a detailed self-answer and accept it.